# Websocket Client Could not find an implementation class

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat7

I will preface this with I am not using any maven dependencies, yet I know that I am missing a jar file `wls-api.jar` (at least that is what I have read).

To remedy this I downloaded the `oracle-weblogic-7.9.jar` but the problem persists.

The exception is thrown at this line

```
 WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
```

Can anyone tell me why this line continuously fails?

UPDATE: upon further reading the examples I see use this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

I have `javax.websocket-api.jar` in the build path of the server and the client as it is required. What am I missing here?

Other update: I forgot to include the error thrown!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
at connect.<init>(connect.java:21)
at test.main(test.java:11)
```

Comment: What exception does the code throw? The fact that you are missing a dependency might still be a problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated my question to include some more information as well as the exception thrown!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

javax.websocket api is only the specification don't have full implementation you may need to take the jar file tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar and try the same example that should solve your problem. i tested with my example and it is working fine.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, what I ended up doing was making a webpage that uses javascript to act as the client. I also have a phone application using the Autobahn websockets api which can be used as a client.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `RuntimeException` you are experiencing is fortunately not generated by any direct coding fault of your own.

The method `getWebSocketContainer()`, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/ContainerProvider.html#getWebSocketContainer()), simply tries to load other classes and get the static instance of the `ContainerProvider` in the server.

> The method looks for the `ContainerProvider` implementation class in the order listed in the `META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider` file, returning the `WebSocketContainer` implementation from the `ContainerProvider` implementation that is not `null`.

This, unfortunately, means that your project is not configured correctly. Double check to make sure this file is included in your project's build path.

If other projects you are looking at are using the Maven dependency you described, I would try to set up your project to do the same.

Hope this helped!

Comment: In the build path I have the javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar do I also have to put this in the lib folder? From what I can tell this jar contains the ContainerProvider

Comment: I don't think the lib folder is anything standard, but try it and see if it works.

Comment: I have set up a few more projects and always get the same exception

Comment: I have one more quick question for you, do you think the project which is set up improperly is the server or the client?

Comment: My guess is that `ContainerProvider` would be involved in a client side implementation, since there is a [specific server side implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html) that extends this.

Comment: Ok, my client is not working, maybe the phone application will have better luck connecting to my server

Answer (score 4):

Adding

> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles/tyrus-standalone-client
>
> compile group: 'org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles', name: 'tyrus-standalone-client', version: '1.9'

to my *build.gradle* file worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The error "Could not find an implementation class" indicates that you don't have a JAR on your classpath that publishes a `ContainerProvider` implementation through a `META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider` file.

A possible client implementation that is not tied to a specific container is the tyrus-container-jdk-client package, also available in a bundle with dependencies and the websocket-api as the tyrus-standalone-client-jdk package.

Note that 1.x versions of Tyrus use the `javax.websocket` API from Java EE, while 2.x versions use `jakarta.websocket` from its successor [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE). So you can also get the error if you use a version Tyrus that is not compatible with the `websocket` API that you are using.