# How to open a websocket directly to a wss: in Java

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to establish a websocket connection in java to wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart%2F&date=2023_01_26-12_41&type=chart to acquire both historical and current chart data.

I have search and read through multiple posts and online resources and I am confused as to the correct procedure to connect to a websocket and acquire incoming data.

I found a post that is very close to what I'm trying to do that open a websocket and uses a ws as the target location. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919865/cant-get-echo-response-from-ws-echo-websocket-org-in-my-websocket-client) I've modified it slightly to implement the solution suggested.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.websocket.*;

@ClientEndpoint
public class ExampleTest2 {

    Session session;

   //Problem resolved, this original echo server is no longer operational
    //private final static String url = "ws://echo.websocket.org:80";
    private final static String url = "wss://websocket-echo.com:443/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        System.out.println("connecting...");
        container.connectToServer(ExampleTest2.class,
                URI.create(url));
        
        System.out.println("Press ENTER key to exit.");
        System.in.read();
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void newMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    @OnOpen
    public void newConnection(Session session) throws IOException {
        this.session = session;
        System.out.println("The connection has been started");
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("hello");

    }
    @OnClose
    public void disconnection() {
        System.out.println("The connection has been ended");
    }
}
```

This is the error output I receive.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
    at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
    at ExampleTest2.main(ExampleTest2.java:14)
```

I continued to search and found a post about that specific error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751630/websocket-client-could-not-find-an-implementation-class) Their solution is to use a different external library. I was using javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar now I've switched to their recommendation of tyrus, tyrus-standalone-client-2.1.2

However it's still not connecting properly.

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:658)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:696)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:849)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:299)
    at ExampleTest2.main(ExampleTest2.java:19)
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 200.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

At this point I am very much in the weeds and I'm not even sure if I'm going in the right direction anymore I'm just following rabbit hole after rabbit hole. At this point I'm trying to resolve indirect problems that I'm not even sure if it is required to accomplish my task of opening a socket and acquiring data.

Any help like code examples or learning material directly related to the task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it has been compiled, it just cannot connect properly. Try specifying port  like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421118/websocket-response-code-was-not-101-200-handshake-error), maybe it will help

Comment: I tried specifying the actual port number. It is my understandin g that ws uses port 80 and wss uses 443. Still same result. I tried "ws://echo.websocket.org:80", "ws://echo.websocket.org:80/", "ws://echo.websocket.org:443"

Comment: I just found the solution. The original server in the code is no longer operation. I used this one instead "wss://websocket-echo.com:443/"

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. The original server in the code is no longer operation. I used this one instead "wss://websocket-echo.com:443/"